# nested exception error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, eclipse

I program in Java with Eclipse and I have the following error :

```
GRAVE: Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte initialisé (context initialized) à l'instance de classe d'écoute (listener) org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [com.sis.artemis.dashboard.statistics.sdis.personnels.service.SdisPersonnelsStatisticsServiceImpl] for bean with name 'sdisPersonnelsStatisticsService' defined in class path resource [resources/sdis-services.xml]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sis/artemis/dashboard/statistics/sdis/personnels/service/SdisPersonnelsStatisticsService
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1238)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:870)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:556)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sis/artemis/dashboard/statistics/sdis/personnels/service/SdisPersonnelsStatisticsService
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:620)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2722)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1124)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1612)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:257)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1256)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1227)
    ... 24 more
20 juil. 2011 11:32:36 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
GRAVE: Error listenerStart
20 juil. 2011 11:32:36 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
GRAVE: Erreur de démarrage du contexte [/artemis-dashboard-spring] suite aux erreurs précédentes
```

But the Class is well defined and I had not this problem this morning and I didn't change anything.

Someone have an idee to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to recognize with this error is that it is a `runtime` problem, usually a classpath issue. Ensure that the class it's complaining about is in your classpath. If the class in question is located in another jar, make sure that jar is in your classpath. If the class is elsewhere in your project, make sure that if you are running it from eclipse, the class is in a source folder or similar.

This error means that the class was present at compile time, but the JVM that is now running your code can no longer find the class in question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
But my class is in my project and I have only one project.

Comment: it looks like you are running this via tomcat. so the problem is probably that the class is not in whatever classpath tomcat is using. is the problematic class (SdisPersonnelsStatisticsService) in a source folder in your project, or in a jar?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using tomcat for a web application server? Tomcat is known to have a class loading problem. Whenever you restart tomcat, also remember to empty its work and temp folders (located directly in the tomcat home folder).

Comment: Does Tomcat really have a well known class loading problem, or is it simply that people don't understand it. Tomcat's classloaders are pretty well documented for each version of Tomcat.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work, i will try to reinstall tomcat, I'll let you know the result.

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what version of Tomcat you are using, but check out the documentation on class loaders in Tomcat;

[Doco for class loader in Tomcat Version 6.0](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html). You said your class is in a "source folder". Maybe try and make sure the compiled .class file is in WEB-INF/classes

It also looks like it can't find **SdisPersonnelsStatisticsService** which may well be the interface class for **SdisPersonnelsStatisticsServiceImpl**. Make sure both (.class files, not .java files) are in your classpath (or WEB-INF/classes)

Answer (score 0):

I have solve my problem like this :
I deleted my tomcat server and reinstall it and now that's work, I don't know exactly why...

Thanks all for your help and to take time for me.